# Should there be a space between numeral and "pc" or "pcs"?

Tags: countable-nouns, numerals

The terms "pc" and "pcs" are often used as short forms for "piece" and "pieces". However, it's not clear how the short forms should be used in conjunction with numerals.

Is it more appropriate or more correct to write "3pcs" (without space) or "3 pcs" (with space)?

Also, should it be "1 pc" or "1 pcs"? (with or without space; the question is about the singular form)

*PS: It seems very difficult to search this on Google.*

Comment: I would include the space, but omit the *s* on the singular form.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of style.  If you are writing for a particular publication, there may be a style guide to follow. I would treat "piece" as being a unit of quantity and would tend to follow the SI convention (see the [BIPM](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/si-brochure/section5-3.html) and, for example, the [US-NIST](https://www.nist.gov/pml/weights-and-measures/writing-metric-units)) that there should be a space and that you should not use the plural.

Pro-tip: always use a non-breaking space so that the unit is not bumped to the next line following the number.